# its shows error like Cannot use namespace 'auth' as a value

Tags: angular

import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '../services/user';

'auth' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133) {this shows when i hover over imort * as auth }

```
import * as auth from 'firebase/auth';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import {
  AngularFirestore,
  AngularFirestoreDocument,
} from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {
  userData: any; // Save logged in user data
  constructor(
    public afs: AngularFirestore, // Inject Firestore service
    public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, // Inject Firebase auth service
    public router: Router,
    public ngZone: NgZone // NgZone service to remove outside scope warning
  ) {
    /* Saving user data in localstorage when 
    logged in and setting up null when logged out */
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe((user) => {
      if (user) {
        this.userData = user;
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.userData));
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')!);
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem('user', 'null');
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')!);
      }
    });
  }
  // Sign in with email/password
  SignIn(email: string, password: string) {
    return this.afAuth
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((result) => {
        this.SetUserData(result.user);
        this.afAuth.authState.subscribe((user) => {
          if (user) {
            this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
          }
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        window.alert(error.message);
      });
  }
  // Sign up with email/password
  SignUp(email: string, password: string) {
    return this.afAuth
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((result) => {
        /* Call the SendVerificaitonMail() function when new user sign 
        up and returns promise */
        this.SendVerificationMail();
        this.SetUserData(result.user);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        window.alert(error.message);
      });
  }
  // Send email verfificaiton when new user sign up
  SendVerificationMail() {
    return this.afAuth.currentUser
      .then((u: any) => u.sendEmailVerification())
      .then(() => {
        this.router.navigate(['verify-email-address']);
      });
  }
  // Reset Forggot password
  ForgotPassword(passwordResetEmail: string) {
    return this.afAuth
      .sendPasswordResetEmail(passwordResetEmail)
      .then(() => {
        window.alert('Password reset email sent, check your inbox.');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        window.alert(error);
      });
  }
  // Returns true when user is looged in and email is verified
  get isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')!);
    return user !== null && user.emailVerified !== false ? true : false;
  }
  // Sign in with Google
  GoogleAuth() {
    return this.AuthLogin(new auth.GoogleAuthProvider()).then((res: any) => {
```

Cannot use namespace 'auth' as a value.ts(2708)

```
this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
    });
  }
  // Auth logic to run auth providers
  AuthLogin(provider: any) {
    return this.afAuth
      .signInWithPopup(provider)
      .then((result) => {
        this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
        this.SetUserData(result.user);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        window.alert(error);
      });
  }
  /* Setting up user data when sign in with username/password, 
  sign up with username/password and sign in with social auth  
  provider in Firestore database using AngularFirestore + AngularFirestoreDocument service */
  SetUserData(user: any) {
    const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<any> = this.afs.doc(
      `users/${user.uid}`
    );
    const userData: User = {
      uid: user.uid,
      email: user.email,
      displayName: user.displayName,
      photoURL: user.photoURL,
      emailVerified: user.emailVerified,
    };
    return userRef.set(userData, {
      merge: true,
    });
  }
  // Sign out
  SignOut() {
    return this.afAuth.signOut().then(() => {
      localStorage.removeItem('user');
      this.router.navigate(['sign-in'])
    });
  }
}
```

please help why i am seeing error in auth but i have declared as auth , i am new to angular to angulart please4 help

Answer (score 0):

when you import firebase it should not be firebase auth compat, your importing it native, but angular fire is using compat library - your mixing firebase version 9 webspace and 8 namespaced together. so just use compat for version 8.

**change import**

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
```

I always create a separate firebase module, and while you're using angular fire, it's just prewritten firebase functions so adjust this to use angular fire on your calls.  then import this to app.module.ts.

angular fire uses some different names for their stuff but in essence its exactly the same:

**firebase-loader.module.ts**

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/functions';
import 'firebase/storage';

import { environment } from './../environment/environment';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig);
}
@NgModule({
    imports:[CommonModule],
    exports:[]
})
export class FirebaseLoadModule{}
```